# Sending e-mail with php confusion

Tags: php, forms, email, post, send

Hopefully just a quick question, I've got a form set up like so - email, name & message. How do it so that on send that it checks whether it has those 3 things, and if so, it then sends to the desired e-mail?

I've tried looking at the php documentation, but I'm not making much sense of it. I'm a little thick today.
Thank-you :)

```
    <form action="" method="post">
        <!--[if IE]> <br> <label for="email">Email</label> <br> <end if -->
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email*" required>
            <br>
        <!--[if IE]> <br> <label for="name">Name</label> <br> <end if -->
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name*" required>
            <br>
        <!--[if IE]> <br> <label for="message">Message</label> <br> <end if -->
        <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Description*" required></textarea>

        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
```

I've got the e-mail php code here - what is going wrong here? (Maybe I could edit that to work?) Complains about 2 parameters, rather than 3.

```
<?php
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (mail('Someemail@tnelectricalsussex.co.uk',  
        "Name: " . $_POST['name'] . PHP_EOL . 
        "Email: " . $_POST['email'] . PHP_EOL . 
        "Message: " . $_POST['message']) ) {
        $status = "Sent"; } } 
?>
```

Comment: you need to firstly capture your submit action, then check  the values of the fields then send the email

Comment: `bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )` you are missing the subject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely forgot to add a subject line (thanks for that @Dagon) - here's the correctly functioning code

php

```
<?php
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (mail('someone@somewhere.co.uk',
        'Enquiries',
        "Name: " . $_POST['name'] . PHP_EOL .
        "Email: " . $_POST['email'] . PHP_EOL .
        "Message: " . $_POST['message']) ) {
        $status = "Sent"; } }
?>
```

html

```
    <form action="" method="post">
        <!--[if IE]> <br> <label for="email">Email</label> <br> <end if -->
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email*" required>
            <br />
        <!--[if IE]> <br> <label for="name">Name</label> <br> <end if -->
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name*" required>
            <br />
        <!--[if IE]> <br> <label for="message">Message</label> <br> <end if -->
        <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Description*" required></textarea>

        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
```

Comment: seems to be missing the code to check the vars are filled it, that was what i answered.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['message'])){
//send email code
}else{
//dont
}
```